# A better way to target nth-child elements that are added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am finding the following methods a bit monotonous when a new video is added. Basically I am targeting every nth-child that is added.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li:nth-child(5) img").appendTo("li:nth-child(5) .video-gradient");
    $("li:nth-child(6) img").appendTo("li:nth-child(6) .video-gradient");
    $("li:nth-child(7) img").appendTo("li:nth-child(7) .video-gradient");
    $("li:nth-child(8) img").appendTo("li:nth-child(8) .video-gradient");
    $("li:nth-child(9) img").appendTo("li:nth-child(9) .video-gradient");
}
```

is there a better way I can implement code (lets ay in a for loop) that would prevent me from having to append element nth-child to a video element that is added?

Many thanks
Robbie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a **for loop?**

```
for (var i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
     $("li:nth-child(" + i + ") img").appendTo("li:nth-child(" + i + ") .video-gradient");
}
```

Comment: `$("li:nth-child("+i+") img").appendTo("li:nth-child("+i+") .video-gradient");`

Comment: or in es6, `$(\`li:nth-child(${i}) img\`)`

Comment: Thanks guys, saved me a headache! Thanks again

Comment: @rabbie make for loop more dynamic by var items = $("yourul li")  ; items.each(function(idx, li) {})